# Is Apache Camel irrelevant when Spring Cloud is used?

Tags: apache-camel, mule, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I am involved in the design of a service that uses Spring Cloud and Apache Camel. I was taken aback today when a colleague asked (maybe advocating would be a better term) whether we really need Apache Camel. From his perspective, most of the downstream systems we talk to are REST-based and therefore, no integration framework should be needed. If my recollection is correct, he also implied that Microservices and Integration Frameworks are incompatible.

I started passionately suggesting that Spring Cloud helps solve a deployment/ops issue while Integration frameworks solve integration issues and that they have orthogonal requirements.

Here are some of the protocols the system will be using to communicate:

```
REST
SOAP
AMQP
Azure SDK
AWS SDK (S3, SimpleBD, etc.)
Dropbox SDK
Paypal SDK
Braintree SDK
Caching (Memcached, EhCache)
Async (VM, Direct-VM, SEDA, SEDA-VM)
Facebook
Twitter
FTP
SMTP
File IO
SOLR/Elesticsearch
Quartz
```

Unknown protocols: as we integrate in customers environment we need to integrate with their systems. The communication protocols are yet unknown.

The following statement by Martin Fowler and James Lewis seems to suggest that ESB and Microservices are incompatible: "We can't resist mentioning Jim Webber's statement that ESB stands for "Egregious Spaghetti Box". Now, how far do you think this statement applies to an integration framework such as Apache Camel?

And more generally, does my colleague have a point? Does this mean that integration patterns have no place in microservices?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Camel is not really an ESB ([unless you want it to be](http://camel.apache.org/is-camel-an-esb.html)), but rather a language/framework to connect "stuff" in a message oriented fashion.

If you feel you can use a concise syntax and flexible swiss army knife to connect "stuff" in your microsservices, sure - use Apache Camel. If you rather solve your integration code in other ways, do so.